# Custom Size for Docking a control button on a Windows Form

Tags: vb.net

I have a button docked in a Windows Form TabControl. I want it to be docked to the bottom right corner while keeping my defined size. The default docking styles are Left, Right, Top, Bottom or Fill.

How can I set the button to be a custom size, while keeping it docked to the bottom right corner?

Comment: Position it in the bottom right corner using the designer.  Then change the Anchor to Bottom + Right so it stays in that corner.  You'll need to do something with the TabControl as well, probably Dock or Anchor on all four sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take a look at the `Anchor` Property instead of `Dock`.

Comment: KekuSemau, this doesn't hold the position if I resize the form.

Comment: Hope you could make it work with the Great HP having filled in the lacking details ;-)